# how to create Sum Function in Spring JPA + Query DSL using PathBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have query like below

```
select sum(qty)... from table where productname = 'Pepsi' group by product.
```

i have created below `PathBuilder` `QueryDSL` Spring code :-

```
PathBuilder<Stock> entityPath = new PathBuilder<Stock>(Stock.class, "stock");
BooleanPath path = entityPath.getBoolean("productname");
BooleanExpression wherecondition = path.eq("pepsi");

NumberPath<Double> path = entityPath.getNumber("qty", Double.class);
NumberExpression<Double> sumfunction= path.castToNum(Double.class).sum();
```

i am using JPA repository to get pagable data like below :-

```
Page<Stock> page = stockRepository.findAll(wherecondition,pageable);
```

i don't know how to use above `sumfunction` with JPA Repository. as i can't combine `BooleanExpression` and `NumberExpression`

Comment: Any specific reason to use query dsl?

Comment: because query are dynamic based on filter coming from frontend

Comment: Is this the only where conditon productname = 'Pepsi' or any other conditions you have? I'm assuming value of productname is dynamic i.e., Pepsi might change depending on user selection.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this

```
@Configurable
public interface XXRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<xx, String> {

@Query(value = "select sum(qty)... from table where productname = ?1 group by product", nativeQuery = true)
      public String findSumOfQty(String productname);
}
```

xx = your entity name which represents the table.

Comment: there can we n number of where condition thats why i cant use @Query annotation .